# DeadObjectException occurs after UNEXPECTED_SERVICE_DISCONNECTION (ate.g, ate.h)

Tags: android-youtube-api

Device: HM NOTE 1W

Android Version: 4.4.2

YouTube Player Library Version: 1.2.1

Steps:

1. Play video with YouTubePlayerSupportFragment, in a DialogFragment(android.support.v4.app)
2. Kill background processes - some phone provides this feature with a shortcut, e.g. long-pressing menu key at MIUI
3. onError with UNEXPECTED_SERVICE_DISCONNECTION
4. DeadObjectException throws

How to fix? How to prevent?

stack trace:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.DeadObjectException
           at aof.g(SourceFile:435)
           at als.g(SourceFile:124)
           at akr.d(SourceFile:306)
           at akr.onTouchEvent(SourceFile:459)
           at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7790)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2316)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2013)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2322)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1985)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2322)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1985)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2322)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1985)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2322)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1985)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2322)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1985)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2322)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1985)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2145)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1577)
           at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:757)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2093)
           at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7981)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4432)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4303)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3894)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3863)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3970)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3871)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4027)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3894)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3863)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3871)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6164)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6144)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6098)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6294)
           at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
           at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
           at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5347)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:835)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
    Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
           at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java)
           at ate.g(SourceFile:308)
           at aof.g(SourceFile:432)
           at als.g(SourceFile:124)
           at akr.d(SourceFile:306)
           at akr.onTouchEvent(SourceFile:459)
           at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7790)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2316)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2013)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2322)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1985)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2322)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1985)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2322)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1985)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2322)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1985)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2322)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1985)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2322)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1985)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2145)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1577)
           at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:757)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2093)
           at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7981)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4432)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4303)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3894)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3863)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3970)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3871)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4027)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3894)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3863)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3871)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6164)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6144)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6098)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6294)
           at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
           at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
           at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5347)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:835)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

another stack trace:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.DeadObjectException
           at aof.h(SourceFile:447)
           at als.h(SourceFile:130)
           at akr.g(SourceFile:402)
           at akr.onAnimationEnd(SourceFile:386)
           at android.view.animation.Animation$3.run(Animation.java:374)
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5347)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:835)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
    Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
           at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java)
           at ate.h(SourceFile:322)
           at aof.h(SourceFile:444)
           at als.h(SourceFile:130)
           at akr.g(SourceFile:402)
           at akr.onAnimationEnd(SourceFile:386)
           at android.view.animation.Animation$3.run(Animation.java:374)
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5347)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:835)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```